# citation number color

Tags: bibtex, citing

I am writing my thesis in latex. But I wanna change "some" citation numbers color in text. my citation number color setting is as follows:

```
    \usepackage[unicode=true,pagebackref=true,
colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,final]{hyperref}
    %\usepackage{todonotes}
    \usepackage[firstpage]{draftwatermark}
    \SetWatermarkText{\ \ \ pishnevis}
    \SetWatermarkScale{1.2}
}
{ 
    \usepackage[pagebackref=false,colorlinks,
    linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
    %\usepackage[disable]{todonotes} % final without TODOs
}
```

as you see, the above setting makes my citation number color to blue. but I want to change some citation colors to black.

for example only:

```
\cite{turnow2012flow}
```

changes to black not blue.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `\hypersetup` command to change the citation command.  Enclosing it in a group `{...}` will make the change.  Thus for example

```
\newcommand{\redcite}[1]{{\hypersetup{citecolor=red}\cite{#1}}}
```

provides a basic citation command that prints the citation in red instead of the current default.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\redcite}[1]{{\hypersetup{citecolor=red}\cite{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\cite{article-minimal}

\redcite{article-minimal}

\cite{article-minimal}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}

\end{document}
```